# Filter an array with other array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I've got 2 arrays:

`array1` contains objects of type `object1`. `object1` has a property `id`.

`array2` contains objects of type `object2`. `object2` has a property `object1Id`.

I know, that `array2` contains objects with ids which always are in `array1`, but `array1` can have more (or equal) objects.
To show it:

[image: Arrays]

So to simplify: `array1` has all objects, `array2` has new objects. How to get an array with old objects..? I'm trying to do it with predicate, but it feels odd to do a loop and insert each `object1Id` to the predicate. Is there any other option? How to do it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a predicate, and you don't need a loop if you use KVC.

Get the array of ids that should be excluded:

```
NSArray *excludeIds = [array2 valueForKey@"object1Id"];
```

Create the predicate:

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (id IN %@)", excludeIds];
```

Then filter:

```
NSArray *oldObjects = [array1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to perform a set operations. What can be helpful is `NSMutableSet` class. Use `setWithArray` to create sets. Then use methods like:

- `unionSet:`
- `minusSet:`
- `intersectSet:`
- `setSet:`

To get subsets that match your criteria.

Source: [NSMutableSet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableSet)

Hope it helps.

Comment: This approach is generally more suited to arrays / collections containing the same type of object

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray*            oldIds = [array2 valueForKeyPath:@"object1Id"];
NSPredicate*        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (id IN %@)", oldIds];
NSArray*            objects = [array1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```